# Using Remove-Item with Credentials

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I am attempting to use the Remove-Item cmdlet as part of an automation for a system.  The files are stored on a server that requires elevated rights to perform the file deletion.  I have access to a domain admin account that I use for such automation scripts.

The code below will build the PSCredential object:

```
$password = New-Object System.Security.SecureString
"passwordhere".ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object { $password.AppendChar($_) }
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("domain\username",$password)
$cred
```

I am passing this object to the following action:

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath $path -Force -Credential $cred
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear to me if the files are local (you're running the script on the server) or remote (on another machine).  If local try running the command using a background job and pass in the credentials to Start-Job:

```
$job = Start-Job { Remove-Item -LiteralPath $path -force } -cred $cred 
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

If they're remote, try using remoting:

```
Invoke-Command -computername servername `
               -scriptblock { Remove-Item -LiteralPath $path -force } `
               -Cred $cred
```

Note: This requires that you execute Enable-PSRemoting on the remote machine.

In general, putting raw passwords in your script isn't a great idea.  You can store the password in an encrypted manner using DPAPI and later, only that user account can decrypt the password e.g.:

```
# Stick password into DPAPI storage once - accessible only by current user 
Add-Type -assembly System.Security 
$passwordBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("Open Sesame") 
$entropy = [byte[]](1,2,3,4,5) 
$encrytpedData = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Protect( ` 
                       $passwordBytes, $entropy, 'CurrentUser') 
$encrytpedData | Set-Content -enc byte .\password.bin 

# Retrieve and decrypted password 
$encrytpedData = Get-Content -enc byte .\password.bin 
$unencrytpedData = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect( ` 
                       $encrytpedData, $entropy, 'CurrentUser') 
$password = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($unencrytpedData) 
$password
```

Comment: I agree that hardcoding a password is a bad idea, but it was a requirement for testing from my host.  I decided to open up our server used for such automation and I logged in as the domain account.  From here I was able to test successfully.  Remove-Item is not able to accept Credential informaiton from the best I can find.

I will give you credit as the answer because the DPAPI stuff is righteous.

Comment: Thanks.  WRT rename-item and -credential you are right when it comes to the filesystem provider.  Keep in mind though that rename-item is meant to work across various different providers (registry, function, etc).  Did you know you can copy and rename functions? PowerShell is pretty cool in this way. You can copy your prompt function to a different name, experiment with a new prompt function, and then restore the old one when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Remove-Item can fail due to authorisation. Alternatively, either find the reference for each file and hit it with a .Delete() or move all of the files to the recycle bin.

```
foreach ($svr in $computers) 
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $svr { 

    $folderitems = Get-ChildItem $cachefolder -Recurse

    # Method 1: .Delete
    foreach ($cachefolderitem in $cachefolderitems)
    {
        if ($cachefolderitem -like "*.ini")
        {
            $cachefolderitem.Delete()
        }
    }

   # Method 2: Move all matching files to the recycle bin
   Move-Item "$cachefolder\*.ini" 'C:\$Recycle.Bin' -Force 
}
```